# Yii - PHP error after content saying that LogDetailFilter couldn’t be found

Tags: php, yii

Ok, I can't figure this one out for the life of me. I'm using Yii 1.1.8.

If I do this:

```
function actionEdit()
{
    $this->render('//user/edit');
}
```

I get a PHP error after the content saying that `LogDetailFilter` couldn’t be found when it was trying to autoload it in `Yiibase.php` on line 421.

But if I do this:

```
function actionEdit()
{
    $this->render('//user/edit');
    die;
}
```

I have no problems. Any thoughts how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error in your config file related to what / how you are logging things. Yii runs all of the Yii::log / Yii::trace calls after it has rendered content (using the onApplicationEnd event), which is why using die prevents your logging from having errors.

If you post your logging info, we can point out the exact spot if you need it